# Left Join not working with WHERE condition set to <>

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Before I ask this question I must admit that I am new to SQL but here it goes:

I have 3 tables: **Crown Facility**, **tblSubProjects**, and **lnkSubProjectFacility**.

I use lnkSubProjectFacility to assign facilities to sub-projects and vice-verse. When the user selects a sub-project from a combo box **(cboAddFacSubProject)** in a form, the `AfterUpdate` event in the combo box causes the 2 listboxes to populate with the associated records in the lnkSubProjectFacility table records.

The LEFT listbox (**lstAddSubProjectFacilities**) displays all facilities associated with the sub-project and the RIGHT (**lstAddSubProFac**) displays all available remaining facilities that the user can assign, with a command button, and remove a available facility from the right listbox and moving it to the left (thus creating a new record in the **lnkSubProjectFacility** table).

Everything works fine except I cannot seem to get the right listbox to populate with the correct available facilities in the combo box's `AfterUpdate` event with the VBA code below:

```
Private Sub cboAddFacSubProject_AfterUpdate()
Dim strSQL As String, strSQL2 As String

'String SQL statment variable for the LEFT listbox - to display all ASSIGNED facilities
strSQL = "SELECT [CROWN Facility].FACILITY_ID, " & _
        "[CROWN Facility].FACILITY_NAME, " & _
        "lnkSubProjectFacility.SUBPROJECT_ID " & _
        "FROM [CROWN Facility] INNER JOIN lnkSubProjectFacility " & _
        "ON [CROWN Facility].FACILITY_ID = lnkSubProjectFacility.FACILITY_ID " & _
        "WHERE lnkSubProjectFacility.SUBPROJECT_ID =" & Me.cboAddFacSubProject & " " & _
        "ORDER BY [CROWN Facility].FACILITY_NAME"

'String SQL statment variable for the RIGHT listbox - to display all AVAILABLE facilities
strSQL2 = "SELECT [CROWN Facility].FACILITY_ID, " & _
        "[CROWN Facility].FACILITY_NAME, " & _
        "lnkSubProjectFacility.SUBPROJECT_ID " & _
        "FROM [CROWN Facility] LEFT JOIN lnkSubProjectFacility " & _
        "ON [CROWN Facility].FACILITY_ID = lnkSubProjectFacility.FACILITY_ID " & _
        "WHERE lnkSubProjectFacility.SUBPROJECT_ID <>" & Me.cboAddFacSubProject & " " & _
        "ORDER BY [CROWN Facility].FACILITY_NAME"

'RowSource for the LEFT listbox - to display all assigned facilities
lstAddSubProjectFacilities.RowSource = strSQL

'RowSource for the RIGHT listbox - to display all available facilities
lstAddSubProFac.RowSource = strSQL2

'This is just updating a label showing the count of items in the left listbox
lblListCt.Caption = lstAddSubProjectFacilities.ListCount & " Facilities Selected"

End Sub
```

After executing this code, everything is fine in the left listbox, with all assigned records for that sub-project showing correctly. However, despite the right listbox excluding all facilities shown in the left, it also excludes ANY facilities that were assigned to any other sub-projects in that table.

In addition for searching for hours for this question, I have experimented with the `strSQL2` variable by trying to add `IS NULL` at the end (which of course does not work) and many other things such as changing the JOIN types. Most recently, I changed `WHERE` to `AND` which returns nothing.

I am sure there is a fairly simple solution to this but I would be very appreciative of any assistance to get me there!

Note: I am using Access 2010 but I do not think that makes any difference.

**EDIT: Here is the structure for the lnkSubProjectFacility table:**

```
SUBPROJECT_ID    FACILITY_ID
7                20000003   
7                20000025   
7                20000027   
8                20010302   
8                20021781   
9                20040035   
9                20044392   
10               20045465
17               10000282   
17               10000452   
17               10000844   
21               20000005   
21               20000019   
21               20000026
```

**CROWN Facility table structure:**

```
FACILITY_ID FACILITY_NAME
20000003    Barnes
20000025    Bio-Medical Applications
20000027    Barnes Center
20010302    Atlantic
20021781    Anthonys Hospital
20040035    Black Hawk
20044392    Ames
20045465    Arnold
10000282    BETHANY
10000452    ANDOVER
10000844    Ankeny
20000005    Columbia
20000019    Baptist
20000026    Childrens Hospital
```

**tblSubProjects table structure:**

```
SUBPROJECT_ID    SUBPROJECT          
7            Service Project1
7            Service Project1
7            Service Project1
8            Service Project2
8            Service Project2
9            Service Project3
9            Service Project3
10           Service Project4
17           CatheterReduction1
17           CatheterReduction1
17           CatheterReduction1
21           Patient Access3
21           Patient Access3
21           Patient Access3
```

Comment: what data type is `cboAddFacSubProject`?

Comment: `cboAddFacSubProject` is an object, it is the property name of the combo box which is used to execute the code above.

Comment: When you remove the `where` clause it returns data, correct?

Comment: Yes, it returns all of the facilities listed in Crown Facility duplicates the ones that were already assigned by how many times they were assigned.

Comment: As a wild guess, what do you get if you change the *strSQL2* `WHERE` clause to this? `"WHERE lnkSubProjectFacility.SUBPROJECT_ID <>" & cboAddFacSubProject & " OR lnkSubProjectFacility.SUBPROJECT_ID Is Null"`

Comment: For example; if a facility were listed under 4 sub-projects then it would be listed 4 times. If a facility were not listed at all, it would only return the result once.

Comment: use a `group by` clause so that duplicates are removed

Comment: `GROUP BY [CROWN Facility].FACILITY_ID, [CROWN Facility].FACILITY_NAME, lnkSubProjectFacility.SUBPROJECT_ID"` will remove duplicates from the result

Comment: @HansUp - Actually, that got me really close! All of the non-listed facilities are now showing but I'm still getting the repeating facilities. Now all I need is to omit the repeated results. I assume I can do that with `GROUP BY`, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Without seeing actual data, `DISTINCT` would be my first guess: `SELECT DISTINCT [CROWN Facility].FACILITY_ID, [CROWN Facility].FACILITY_NAME, lnkSubProjectFacility.SUBPROJECT_ID` Does that get what you want?

Comment: @czifro - Sorry about that, I was testing that exactly and just saw your reply. It seems that the ORDER BY conflicts with GROUP BY so I am currently trying to integrate them both into this statement.

Comment: @HansUp - Using `SELECT DISTINCT` isn't working but GROUPBY seems to.

Comment: @HansUp & @czifro - Apologies, please disregard my last comment. Neither `SELECT DISTINCT` nor `GROUP BY` is working. :(

Comment: could you update you post with instances of both tables? Use fake data if you cannot share any real data

Comment: Sorry about that, I added a piece of the lnkSubProjectFacility table. I'll go ahead and do the others now.

Comment: The schema of your lnkSubProjectFacility table does not follow best practice. Is it too late to change your schema?

Comment: No, certainly not. I actually planned on changing that because I knew that the repeated data should be removed.

Comment: does `tblSubProjects` actually have duplicate data?

Comment: No, only the lnkSubProjectFacility did. I actually made a copy of the file and removed it. Everything still works fine (except for the duplicates and integrating ORDER BY and GROUP BY in the same statement). I also updated the post with the improved table design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that lnkSubProjectFacility is meant to relate Facility to tblSubProjects. lnkSubProjectFacility seems to be the only table I would change as far as schema

```
lnkSubProjectFacility
         SPF_Id,  SubProject_Id, Facility_Id
           1          7           20000003
           2          7           20000025
           3          7           20000027
           4          8           20010302
           .          .               .
           .          .               .
           .          .               .
```

try to normalize the data as much as possible that way it is easier to write queries.

if you are trying to write a query that gets all facilities that have not been assigned a subproject:

```
  select [CROWN FACILITY].FACILITY_ID, [CROWN FACILITY].FACILITY_NAME
  from [CROWN FACILITY] as CF
  where not exists (select * 
                    from lnkSubProjectFacility as lSPF
                    where CF.FACILITY_ID == lSPF.FACILITY_ID)
```

i believe that query should work, hard to tell when I cannot test it.
sometimes a join is not the answer. a join can look a lot nicer, but sometimes a subquery is better

Comment: Thanks, I'll mess with a query instead. I'm trying to get a all of the facilities which haven't been assigned a specific sub-project (chosen by the user with a combo box) which is why I was thinking that was the only way to go.

Comment: The schema is just a recommendation. The query, or a query using `not exists`, should solve your issue.